# Internationalization in Java

Tags: java, internationalization, bundles

I am trying to use I18N in my program but it doesn't work properly. The console doesn't show a German symbol, but rather '?'.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LocaleDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {

            Locale l = new Locale("ge", "GE");
            ResourceBundle r = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle_ge");
            displayValues(r);
        }

public static void displayValues(ResourceBundle bundle) {
    System.out.println("hello message:" + bundle.getString("wish"));
}
}
```

File `Bundle_ge.properties` has this text: `wish=großer`

And here is the result:

[image]

What is my mistake? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to do some research about code pages and encodings.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you're creating a locale, but you're not using it, and you load Bundle_ge, instead of loading Bundle, and letting the getBundle method load the appropriate file based on the locale. It should be `ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", l)`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, why I should use `Bundle` instead of `Bundle_ge`? My properties file has such a title: `Bundle_ge.properties` Also I may have lots of properties files for different languages.

Comment: That's the whole point of getBundle(): you pass a bundle base name ("Bundle" in this case), and a locale (ge_GE in this case, but the correct codes would be de_DE), and the method returns the appropriate bundle, delegating to its parent (as documented). So it looks for a key in Bundle_de_DE if it exists there, then fallbacks to Bundle_de, then fallbacks to Bundle. This is all documented in the javadoc. Read it. That's what it's for. Java also has an official i18n tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/index.html

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? I use Eclipse Neon.

Comment: @LuckyProgrammer Eclipse Neon is full of glitches and bugs that were fixed in [Oxygen](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/oxygen1a). I suggest you upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Message bundles are read with ISO-8859-1 encoding. So they have to be stored in ISO-8859-1. Make sure they are. Most likely yours are stored as UTF-8?!

Alternatively - use the unicode code for special chars.
For german umlauts and SZ:

```
ä = \u00e4
Ä = \u00c4
ö = \u00f6
Ö =\u00d6
ü = \u00fc
Ü = \u00dc
ß = \u00df
```

There are tools that convert resource bundles automatically. I.e. Resource Bundle Editor in IntelliJ does that for you.

See if that solves your problem.

Comment: it's strange but russian symbols my program shows, but german doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this in Settings/Editor/File Encodings. Probably you will need to save files again.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-encoding-for-properties-files.html